# Split the date! (It's a string actually)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, regex

I want to split this kind of String :

```
"14:30 - 19:30" or "14:30-19:30"
```

inside a javascript array like `["14:30", "19:30"]`

so I have my variable

```
var stringa = "14:30 - 19:30";
var stringes = [];
```

Should i do it with regular expressions? I think I need an help

Comment: I would just split on the dash and trim the results...maybe if you are unsure that `stringa` will follow the format, test with a regex...

Comment: `var arr = stringa.split('-').map(function(x) { return x.trim()});`

Comment: adeneo, for some reasons, always have an inline solution where most doesn't, lol. +1

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `str.split` :

```
var stringa = "14:30 - 19:30";
var res = str.split("-");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know that the only `'-'` present will be the delimiter, you can start by splitting on that:

```
let parts = input.split('-');
```

If you need to get rid of whitespace surrounding that,  you should trim each part:

```
parts = parts.map(function (it) { return it.trim(); });
```

To validate those parts, you can use a regex:

```
parts = parts.filter(function (it) { return /^\d\d:\d\d$/.test(it); });
```

Combined:

```js
var input = "14:30 - 19:30";
var parts = input.split('-').map(function(it) {
  return it.trim();
}).filter(function(it) {
  return /^\d\d:\d\d$/.test(it);
});

document.getElementById('results').textContent = JSON.stringify(parts);
```

```html
<pre id="results"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
var stringa = "14:30 - 19:30";
var stringes = stringa.split("-");   // string is "14:30-19:30" this style

or

var stringes = stringa.split(" - "); // if string is "14:30 - 19:30"; style so it includes the spaces also around '-' character.
```

The split function breaks the strings in sub-strings based on the location of the substring you enter inside it "-"

. the first one splits it based on location of "-" and second one includes the spaces also " - ".

*also it looks more like 24 hour clock time format than data as you mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
var stringa = '14:30 - 19:30';
var stringes = stringa.split("-");
```

Answer (score 0):

.split is probably the best way to go, though you will want to prep the string first.  I would go with `str.replace(/\s*-\s*/g, '-').split('-')`.  to demonstrate:

```
var str = "14:30 - 19:30"
var str2 = "14:30-19:30"
console.log(str.replace(/\s*-\s*/g, '-').split('-')) //outputs ["14:30", "19:30"]
console.log(str2 .replace(/\s*-\s*/g, '-').split('-')) //outputs ["14:30", "19:30"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that you can pass a [*RegExp*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) into [`str.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```
'14:30 - 19:30'.split(/\s*-\s*/); // ["14:30", "19:30"]
'14:30-19:30'.split(/\s*-\s*/); // ["14:30", "19:30"]
```